# gmaps4rails empty map... Javascript issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I've looked through many similar questions, and tried their suggestions, but I'm still getting a completely empty map (no controls).  I'm pretty sure this is something simple...

Using Rails 3.1.2 and Ruby 1.9.2-p290

I have this in my footer:

```
<% = yield :scripts %>
```

Assets are enabled.  My application.js has this line BEFORE the jquery lines:

```
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
```

(I have also tried //= require ./gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js)

The assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails directory exists and it contains scripts.

My model code:

```
# 01/06/2012 - For Gmaps4Rails
    acts_as_gmappable
...
    def gmaps4rails_address
    # 01/06/2012 - For Gmaps4Rails
    "#{self.city}, #{self.country}" 
    end
```

My View:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

My controller:

```
@json = Party.all.to_gmaps4rails
@parties = Party.all
```

I am sure the JSON object has data, because (if I add it to the view) I can see it when the page renders:
[{"lat":15.87,"lng":100.993},{"lat":37.0902,"lng":-95.7129}] 
Also, if I look in my local MySQL database those rows have latitude and longitude set, and gmaps=1

However, all I get is a large, completely empty map area (no controls).

My hunch is that the /gmaps4rails/... javascript is NOT getting pulled in.  If I view source, I can see application.js, but it contains no mention of gmaps.

If I look in firebug under scripts... The only \localhost\assets script I see is application.js.  Shouldn't I see googlemaps.js also?

The Gmaps javascript **does** appear in view source at the end (... Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle(); ...)

I converted this rails app to a Rails 3 app about two months ago.  Perhaps something that is normally automatically setup in a new rails 3 app generation is not enabled for me?  Coffeescript?

What might I be doing wrong here?  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a <%= yield :head %> in your header?

Comment: Did you try to copy the js files in your app using the rake task?

Comment: apneadiving:  As for the yield :head:  I have tried it both ways and it has no impact.  The documentation says Rails 3.0.x **only** so I am assuming it is NOT necessary in 3.1.  I just put it back in and it had no impact.   As for the rake task, do you mean the `rails generate gmaps4rails:install` command?  Yes, I have done that and the files \gmaps4rails\gmaps4rails.base.coffee and \gmaps4rails\gmaps4rails.googlemasp.coffee both exist in that subdirectory.  I'm beginning to think that I'm missing something required to process coffeescript since I upgraded from a prior rails version...

Comment: **For next users having the same problem** : I solved it by adding not only the `//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps` to the application.js, but also the `//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base` line. After what everything seems to be working as expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
The problem was that my asset pipeline was all messed up due to the migration from an earlier rails version.  Specifically, I had to do the following things to resolve this:
First, add these lines in my gemfile:

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
# 01/14/2012 - DC needed to add this manually because this was UPGRADED!
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# 01/14/2012 - Needed this on linux to clear this bug: line 8: missing name after . operator
gem 'therubyracer', '>= 0.8.2'
```

Then a **bundle update**

I also deleted my \public\assets\application.js.  I think this wasn't automatically getting recompiled because it was left over from my prior rails version.

After that, BooYah!  It is working!

Comment: Sure, sorry!  I thought I had already.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A quick test of whether Coffeescript is working corrently in your app is to create a new `file.coffee` in `app/assets/javascripts/` and then adding a `//= require file` line. If your rendered page then references that new file, or (assuming your asset pipeline is set this way) if your rendered `application.js` includes the rendered `file.coffee`, everything would appear to be working properly.

If this is not happening, try creating a new rails 3.1.2 app and performing a recursive `diff` on it against your app.<sup>**1**</sup> Specifically, look in the `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/*` files.  Then obviously, just keep an eye out for anything that may be missing from your app. There are a few configuration statements related to the asset pipeline that Rails generates with the new app generator, that you may have missed during upgrade. I've run into hitches before, when upgrading apps to 3.1, and this has always been enlightening.

My final suggestion that occurs to me is that you seem to be specifying the `.js` extension in your `application.js` `require` directive. This is certainly not necessary and may be the reason it's not being pulled in.

---

<sup>1. [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is a fantastic graphical tool for this, if you're using Linux or OSX.</sup>